# Is $O (N \log N)$ FFT speed the fastest we can ever attain?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, dft

I am wondering about whether or not there is a theoretical limit as to the speed at which we can compute a DFT. We all know that the FFT executes in $O (N \log N)$ time. However, is this a lower bound of some sort?

Might there be yet faster algorithms that have yet to be discovered which we do not currently know about that are faster, or is this a holy boundary that cannot be crossed?

Edit: Apparently this is a [known unsolved problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_computer_science) in CS, (thanks to @John).

So, what are the details of the problem? Where would one start to try to make improvements?

Comment: Wikipedia has that on the list of unsolved problems in computer science: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_computer_science

Comment: @John Thanks - does this mean that they know it can be lowered, (but do not know to what value), or does this mean that that they are not even sure if it can even be lowered?

Comment: Both. The lower bound is not known.

Comment: @John I updated the question, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: there's something called the Winograd fourier transform that was supposed to be $O(N)$.

Comment: That bound only applies to N = # of multiplications.

Comment: @John You have to put "@usersName" for them to see your comment

Comment: i saw it anyway.  and @John, yer right.  when the Winograd paper was first published, in the mid 70s, multiplication was still the major expense: say one instruction cycle for every bit in the multiplier.  addition was a single instruction cycle, so i could see where there might be incentive to trade back then, when it doesn't make sense now.

Comment: You can do it in O(N) using a quantum computer and in constant time using optics

Comment: @Aaron Can you expand on why it would be $O(n)$ on a quantum computer, or why it would be done in constant time using optics?

Answer (score 3):

While the general problem remains an open problem in theoretical computer science, there are (randomized) algorithms known as sparse fast fourier transforms which can approximate DFTs to a certain approximation factor when there are only a few DFT coefficients you are concerned with.

You can find some details in these papers and related papers (downloadable [here](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/netmit/sFFT/paper.html)):

- Hassanieh, Haitham, et al. "Nearly optimal sparse Fourier transform." Proceedings of the 44th symposium on Theory of Computing. ACM, 2012.
- Hassanieh, Haitham, et al. "Simple and practical algorithm for sparse Fourier transform." Proceedings of the Twenty-Third Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms. SIAM, 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the ["divide and conquer" algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) in computational paradigm uses O(NlogN) as the lower bound. It provides some sort of balance between space and time complexity. Sort is one of the application for divide and conquer approach. FFT has also been computed using the same "Divide and Conquer" approach.

O(N) algorithms require more space (memory) for computation although it is fast. The only way to make improvement is to improve the speed of the multiplication using different algorithms like karatsuba multiplication, Vedic multiplication, etc.

Comment: **Vedic** multiplication?  Good grief, that has been thoroughly debunked a long time ago.

Comment: Karatsuba is worse than O(N*log(N)), check your sources.

Answer (score 0):

in terms of actual compute complexity- I doubt we can beat N log N.
In terms of time complexity, however-
https://github.com/falseywinchnet/tomatofft/tree/main
as of today, I have published tomato patch fft, which can return results in N.

That's right- FFT in O(N).

Comment: you're aware of Winograd FFT?

Comment: I was not. thankfully, the quickest way to learn, is to be wrong.

Comment: winograd still seems to approach the problem differently, for prime sizes only.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Winograd Fourier Transform](https://www.mdpi.com/2079-9292/11/9/1342#:%7E:text=The%20Winograd%20Fourier%20transform%20algorithm,the%20DFT%20to%20order%20N.) that is ostensibly $O(N)$.